# taking every subsequence in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I wrote this C# code to take every subsequence of a set of words.

```
    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Subsequences(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        var arr = words as string[] ?? words.ToArray();
        int len = arr.Count();
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
            for (int j = 0; i + j <= len; j++)
                yield return arr.Skip(j).Take(i);
    }
```

How would you write this in F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a translation with the same logic:

```
let subsequences words =
    seq {
        let len = Array.length words
        for i = 1 to len - 1 do
            for j = 0 to len - i do
                yield words.[j..j+i-1]
    }
```